# Create Class Dynamically During Runtime

Tags: c#, .net

Hi im trying to create a class dending on data gathered from a user input. Once its chosen id like to the create the field names and the data types based on that and fill that class with data from document effectively creating a list of that Class.

Eg I create a class called Class1 and give it 3 Properties : ID , Name , Weight and define there types as int , string , int

Then I want to fill it with data Eg : (Example in json to show structure)

ID:{
1,
2,
3
},
Name:{
A,
B,
c
},
Weight:{
10,
20,
30
}

Ive looked into Reflection and codeDom which both enable for me to make the Class but i cannot work out how to write to that new classes properties.

Code for codeDom Version:

```
string className = "BlogPost";

        var props = new Dictionary<string, Type>() {
            { "Title", typeof(string) },
            { "Text", typeof(string) },
            { "Tags", typeof(string[]) }
        };

        createType(className, props);
```

I Create The Properties and their Types

```
static void createType(string name, IDictionary<string, Type> props)
    {
        var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider(new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "CompilerVersion", "v4.0" } });
        var parameters = new CompilerParameters(new[] { "mscorlib.dll", "System.Core.dll" }, "Test.Dynamic.dll", false);
        parameters.GenerateExecutable = false;

        var compileUnit = new CodeCompileUnit();
        var ns = new CodeNamespace("Test.Dynamic");
        compileUnit.Namespaces.Add(ns);
        ns.Imports.Add(new CodeNamespaceImport("System"));

        var classType = new CodeTypeDeclaration(name);
        classType.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public;
        ns.Types.Add(classType);

        foreach (var prop in props)
        {
            var fieldName = "_" + prop.Key;
            var field = new CodeMemberField(prop.Value, fieldName);
            classType.Members.Add(field);

            var property = new CodeMemberProperty();
            property.Attributes = MemberAttributes.Public | MemberAttributes.Final;
            property.Type = new CodeTypeReference(prop.Value);
            property.Name = prop.Key;
            property.GetStatements.Add(new CodeMethodReturnStatement(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), fieldName)));
            property.SetStatements.Add(new CodeAssignStatement(new CodeFieldReferenceExpression(new CodeThisReferenceExpression(), fieldName), new CodePropertySetValueReferenceExpression()));
            classType.Members.Add(property);
        }

        var results = csc.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parameters, compileUnit);
        results.Errors.Cast<CompilerError>().ToList().ForEach(error => Console.WriteLine(error.ErrorText));
    }
```

This is just code i found elsewhere but if this where the code i wanted id do something like

```
var a = new List<BlogPost>()
```

and then

```
a."Property1" = "Title 1"
```

Hope this is informative

Comment: Have you considered `ExpandoObject`?

Comment: Hi Andy, Yes ive looked into it However i cannot access the unknown Properties to assign them. Creating the properties is generally okay but assigning to them is where im mostly struggling

Comment: Why not just stick with a `Dictionary` then? Even if you write the code to make new classes, then how would you expect to use it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection.
Main method to create desired object and populate its properties:

```
    public object GenerateObject(string fullyQualifiedClassName,
                       Dictionary<string, object> nameToValueMap)
    {
        var actualObject = GetInstance(fullyQualifiedClassName);
        if (actualObject == null)
            return actualObject;

        foreach (var prop in nameToValueMap)
        {
            SetPropValue(actualObject, prop.Key, prop.Value);       
        }   
        return actualObject;    
    }
```

Method to create instance of the desired class, based on fully qualified class name:

```
    public object GetInstance(string fullyQualifiedName)
    {
        Type type = Type.GetType(fullyQualifiedName);
        if (type != null)
            return Activator.CreateInstance(type);

        foreach (var asm in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies())
        {
            type = asm.GetType(fullyQualifiedName);
            if (type != null)
                return Activator.CreateInstance(type);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

And last but not least, method to set property's value:

```
    public bool SetPropValue<T>(T obj, string propName, object val)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(propName)) return false;

        var prop = obj?.GetType()
                  .GetProperties()?
                  .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == propName);
        if (prop != null)
        {
            prop.SetValue(obj, val);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use dynamic object using expandoObject?

something like:

```
dynamic blogPost = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
blogPost.Tile = "Mary Water";
blogPost.Text= "your text here";
```

Comment: Because every time you use `dynamic`, a kitten dies. They're horrible things (dynamic variables, not kittens) and should only be used in very particular situations since they are prone to runtime errors, slow and confusing (though kittens can be that too)